# Unprotecting VBA in XLS 2010 via Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I'm working on a solution that will inject VBA modules into an XLS document by using powershell. By using the ComObject Excel.Application I'm able to open a workbook, access the CodeModule, and call AddFromString.

This is all good until I encounter an XLS document that is password protected. Not the sheet itself but the VBAProject. I've tried various approaches, opening the sheet by specifying the password --> $xl.Workbooks.Open($filePath, 1, $false, 5, "123", "123"),  and also calling $workbook.Unprotect("123").

Both of these dont seem to have any impact, and I'm not able to access the workbook component, $workbook.VBProject.VBComponents, like Im able to do for the non-protected documents.

Assume in all instances I know the password in advance.

Comment: VBA does not expose VBProject passwords in its object model.

Comment: The way to access the VBProject is to open the workbook, e.g. $xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application, followed by $xl.Workbooks.Open($filePath), and then $workbook.VBProject